# char const too long in "C"

Tags: c++, c, char, embedded

I'm getting an ***char const too long*** error on if statement.  I searched this error in Google, they suggested to change the single quotes('') to double quotes ("") i.e charRead != "/0".

After compiling the code I'm getting a different error that *"operands of "!=" not same type"*.

How to resolve this?

```
if( (charRead != '/0') && (isalnum(charRead) || isspace(charRead) || ispunct(charRead)) ) ...
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting and post the exact error message you got.

Comment: You sure you didn't want to use `'\0'`? The second error is probably the result of comparing a char with a string.

Comment: You can find the answer to this at http:\\en.wikipedia.org\wiki\Null_character .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/0` are two chars. This is why you get the error message that it is too big to be stored in a char. `\0` is one char which has the byte value 0. This one can be stored in a char.

Answer (score 4):

`'/0'` is not a valid char literal. If you meant it to be a zero byte, you escape it with backslash, like so:  `'\0'`

Comment: It is valid according to the standard: "An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal has type int and implementation-deﬁned value."